# using Comparator class in Java

Tags: jakarta-ee

This is the matrix, where u compare 1st row and 2nd row 1st column value, if its equal u

print and move to 2nd column do the same, if not equal then print the low value and next 3rd column do the same, Now compare 2nd and 3rd row do the same. do this for full matrix sits in ascending order.. How to solve this using Compare class.. help me please

enter code here: int a[][] = {{3,6,5},

```
            {3,5,7},

            {2,1,6},

            {2,1,3},

            {7,8,5},

            {6,3,2}};
```

O/P matrix is

[2 1 3]

[2 1 6]

[3 5 7]

[3 6 5]

[6 3 2]

[7 8 5]

Answer (score 0):

as quick solution might be as follows

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Compare2Darray {
    public static Comparator<Integer[]> getComparator() {
        return new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
            public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
                    if (o1[i].compareTo(o2[i]) != 0) {
                        return o1[i].compareTo(o2[i]);
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }};
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Integer a[][] = {{3,6,5}, {3,5,7}, {2,1,6}, {2,1,3}, {7,8,5}, {6,3,2}};
        Arrays.sort(a, getComparator());
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[i]));
        }
    }
}
```